# GUID Partition Attribute not working on MacOS

Tags: macos, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, gpt, gdisk

I'm trying to prevent automount on a device. The device contains only one FAT32 GPT partition.

I have set the GUID Partition attribute to `63` using `gdisk`  *(i.e. do not automount)*. I have also tried using Diskpart and GPT ATTRIBUTES to `0x8000000000000000` *(i.e. no default drive letter)*.

While both these works on Windows 10, MacOS still mount my partition. How to prevent this on any computer I plug my device ?

- I don't want to hide the partition because MacOS will ask to format.
- I don't want to add an entry to fstab because it works on a single computer only.

Comment: So it mounts *without* asking the user at all. Right? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, that's it.